# SharePoint Workflow 2013 Get Item From Nested Dictionary

Tags: workflow, json, dictionary

I have a sharepoint workflow dictionary in which I have following data:

```
Userlist: [{"Id":3,"Value":"Tim Meier"},{"Id":2,"Value":"Hans Müller"}]
```

This is what I get when I run the log and choose variable dictionary.

The fiels are Dynamic Fiels so I Need to know how I can Access them

Can I Access it via

> Get 2 from Variable: Dictionary (Output to: singleuser) ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to setup a loop with the number of item in your dictionary, keep an index variable to know which item you are currently reading (ie, i=0, i=1, etc...) then the path to one of the item would be: `results(i)/Id` or `results(i)/Value`

So for instance, based on your example, `results(0)/Id` would return `3` and the Value one would return `Tim Meier`